# html-minifier-terser ignores its output argument

Tags: node.js, npm

Within the root directory of my project, I run the following command using `npm` and `html-minifier-terser`:

```
npx html-minifier-terser --input-dir src/ --output-dir dist/  src/index.html -o index.min.html --file-ext html
```

The output file to `dist/` is `index.html` and not `index.min.html`.

I tried to install `html-minifier-terser` globally, which does not help. I then tried to remove the specification of `input` and `output` directories within the command, which resulted in the expected behavior.

Any suggestions why I can't get `dist/index.min.html` to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a little more research, I found a solution on this thread [ng build production should minify index.html in dist](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11360#issuecomment-528679423).

The workaround is to omit using the `input` and `output` directory arguments and instead specify the output path as in `--output dist/index.min.html`.